# Can we prove this after removing one condition?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

mathematicians! I want to ask about redundant condition in the below proof.

---

Suppose there exists a partition $A_{0}, A_{1}, \ldots, A_{k}$ of $\chi$ such that $P(X \in A_{0}) = 0$ and $f_{X}(x)$ is continuous on each $A_{i}$. Further, suppose there exist functions $g_{1}(x), \ldots, g_{k}(x)$, defined on $A_{1}, \ldots, A_{k}$, respectively satisfying

(a) $g(x) = g_{i}(x), for x \in A_{i}$ 
(b) $g_{x}$ is monotone on $A_{i}$ 
(c) the set $Y = \{y: y = g_{i}(x)\}$ is the same for each $i = 1 ,\ldots, k$ 
(d) $g_{i}^{-1}(y)$ has a continuous derivatve on $Y$, for each $i = 1,2,\ldots,k$

Then  $$ f_{Y}(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} f_{X}(g_{i}^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}(y)|\;\;\;, y \in Y$$
and $f_{Y}(y) =0$ otherwise.

---

This is the proof for the above statement.
$$F_{Y}(y) = P[(Y \leq y)\cap(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i})] \\ = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P[(Y \leq y)\cap(A_{i})] \\ =\sum_{i \in I}(F_{X}(g_{i}^{-1}(y) - F(c_{i-1})) + \sum_{i \in I^{c}} F(c_{i-1})-(F_{X}(g_{i}^{-1}(y))$$
where $I$ is the set of indexexs, $i$, such that $g_{i}$ is increasing over $A_{i}$, and $A_{i} = (c_{i-1},c_i]$. Thus by (d), we have 
$$ f_{Y}(y) = \sum_{i\in I} f_{X}(g_{i}^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}(y)| - \sum_{i\in I^c} f_{X}(g_{i}^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}(y)| \\ = \sum_{i=1}^{k} f_{X}(g_{i}^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}(y)|$$

---

My question is that, can we prove this after removing the condition (c) ? I think so, but kind of hard to generate the idea. Can anybody help?

Comment: (c) defines $Y$. It doesn't seem to be possible to even formulate anything if it is removed.

Comment: @user58697 So, what you mean is that the condition (c) isn't even used for the proof. Right?

Comment: No. It *is* used. The mere fact that such $Y$ exists is essential.

Comment: Actually (c) defining a set $Y$ contradicts the rest of the post, seemingly dealing with a random variable $Y$ (unfortunately this $Y$ is not even defined, although my guess would be that $Y=g(X)$).